# Capture entire webpage as a screenshot

Tags: screenshot

I need to capture an entire web page as a screenshot (PNG).

I checked for a few extension (they are saying that they are capturing the full page) but actually, they only capture the visible part of web page.

I am looking for a Google Chrome browser extension as first preference. If some else if available, they are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Screengrab**](http://www.s3blog.org/screengrab.html) is the best screenshot add-on for browsers I know, because it can be highly configured:

- you can save the whole page, the visible area or a selection
- the image format can be chosen between PNG, JPG or BMP
- the automatic name of the created file can be configured
- the functions behind the icon can be configured
- hotkeys can be set
- upload services can be pre-configured

It is:

- translated into a bunch of languages
- open source (MPL2) - at least the Firefox version, no idea about the Chrome/Chromium version
- available [for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/screengrab-fix-version/) and [for Chrome/Chromium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screengrab/fccdiabakoglkihagkjmaomipdeegbpk)

Answer (score 1):

[Firefox Screenshots](https://screenshots.firefox.com/) is a new feature to take, download, collect and share screenshots. To use it, click on the Firefox Screenshot icon on the toolbar.

[NirSoft SiteShoter](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_site_screenshot.html) is a small utility that allows you to save a screenshot of any Web page into a file. It automatically creates hidden window of Internet Explorer, loads the desired Web page, and than save the entire content of the Web page into an image file (.png, .jpg, .tiff, .bmp or .gif).